# cannot find module "lodash"

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

Today I tried to learn more about Google Web Starter Kit so I followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/web-starter-kit/setting-up?hl=en) and after a lot of fight and problem I just tried to start a local server (the first task we’ll look at is: `$ gulp serve`.) and received this error:

C:\gwsk>gulp serve

```
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\gwsk\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\portsc
anner-plus\lib\index.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\gwsk\node_modules\browser-sync\lib\utils.js:6:19)
```

Honestly I'm completely lost here, so any help is pretty welcome. I'm new to node.js, to gulp, I just wanted it to try GWSK but turn into a headache :(... I'm a web designer not developer....

Comment: I had typo in import line `import _ form loadash` instead `import _ from lodash`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Be sure to install lodash in the required folder. This is probably your C:\gwsk directory.

If that folder has a package.json file, it is also best to add --save behind the install command.

```
$ npm install lodash --save
```

The package.json file holds information about the project, but to keep it simple, it holds your project dependencies.

The save command will add the installed module to the project dependencies.

If the package.json file exists, and if it contains the lodash dependency you could try to remove the node_modules folder and run following command:

```
$ npm cache clean    
$ npm install
```

The first command will clean the npm cache. (just to be sure)
The second command will install all (missing) dependencies of the project.

Comment: Hi bohem, to be honest I just forget about this and move on, any way thx a lot for your answer! I will bookmark it and give it a try in a near future ;) for now trying sass + susy + breakpoint. :D

Comment: No problem, I got a web designer sitting behind me and know how hard it can be for none developers to understand technical explanations so tried to keep it superficial. Give a shout when you got it to work or not. Always wanted to try gulp ;)

Comment: As of npm v5 you can run 'npm cache verify'. Although the exact equivalent would be 'npm cache clean --force'

Answer (score 19):

I found deleting the contents of node_modules and performing `npm install` again worked for me.

Comment: Pro tip: Deletion of the `node_modules` folder may take a couple of minutes. Better rename it and delete the renamed folder. This way, you can run `npm install` straight away and do not have to wait until the folder is deleted.

Answer (score 10):

Reinstall 'browser-sync' :

```
rm -rf node_modules/browser-sync
npm install browser-sync --save
```

Comment: This solved my problem! I was using jest and trying to run a single test through VSCode and it kept saying cannot find lodash. Installing this fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Maybe loadash needs to be installed. Usually these things are handled by the package manager. On your command line:

```
npm install lodash
```

or maybe it needs to be globally installed

```
npm install -g lodash
```

Comment: Hi Will! thx for your answer. I tryed what you suggest and recieve a lot of "npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined." :( I try again to run gulp serve and fail again... Now say this: "Starting 'styles' errored after 13 s, Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'"

Answer (score 3):

If there is a `package.json`, and in it there is `lodash` configuration in it. then you should:

```
npm install
```

if in the `package.json` there is no `lodash`:

```
npm install --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

though `npm install lodash` would work, I think that it's a quick solution but there is a possibility that there are other modules not correctly installed in `browser-sync`.

lodash is part of `browser-sync`. The best solution is the one provided by Saebyeok. Re-install `browser-sync` and that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I update node and npm to the latest version and it works.

Answer (score -1):

The above error run the commend line\

please change the command 
 **$ node server**
it's working and server is started