# Cordova Android Upgrade - Cannot find module ‘lodash/object/assign’ Error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, gradle, upgrade

I have build Cordova (version - 2.9) Android App using gradle, now i want to upgrade cordova using **cordova platform update android** command but all time it gives me following error " **Cannot find module ‘lodash/object/assign’ Error** " , i also went through [this](http://community.appgyver.io/t/error-cannot-find-module-lodash-object-assign/4875) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431187/cannot-find-module-lodash) but none of them are working , please guide me to resolve.

[image: Error ScreenCast]

Answer (score 0):

There is no folder **object** in *cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\plist\node_modules\xmlbuilder\node_modules\lodash* -
therefore, require/resolveFilename fails.

Quick and dirty solution: make a copy of the existing folder **fp** in *cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\plist\node_modules\xmlbuilder\node_modules\lodash* and rename it to **object**. I had to copy it two more times (**collection** and **lang** were missing as well).