# Cordova build fails with "Cannot find module lodash/object/assign"

Tags: android, cordova, lodash

After adding Android to an iOS-only Cordova project, cordova build fails with

`Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/object/assign'`

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056209/cordova-android-upgrade-cannot-find-module-lodash-object-assign-error), but there is no xmlbuilder in my plist directory in the globally installed cordova module (/usr/local). So I am unable to try that quick and dirty solution.

The problem persists even after removing Android and re-running cordova build. I'm not aware of having made any changes to the project since last running cordova build except for a tiny change to a js file in www.

**Versions**: cordova -v: 5.4.1, node -v: v4.2.4, npm -v lodash: 2.14.12 (if that's even the one used here),

**cordova plugins list**: cordova-hot-code-push-plugin 1.2.5 "Hot Code Push Plugin"
cordova-media-with-compression 2.0.15 "Media With Compression: Alpha Software Edition"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.1.3 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-iosrtc 2.2.2 "iosrtc"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.2.1-dev "Capture"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.0.10 "SocialSharing"
cordova-universal-links-plugin 1.1.0 "Universal Links Plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.5.3 "PushPlugin"

Comment: For the new version the right folder for assign module is "cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\lodash\object\", please check if   file "assign.js" is still there or not.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/lodash/object/assign.js exists...

Comment: Have you tried using "npm install -g cordova@5.4.1" to reinstall the cordova of version 5.4.1?

Comment: Just did so, but the problem persists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it seems to be an issue with a plugin.

I created a separate blank project, added all plugins, added the android platform, then "cordova build" and – boom – the same response again. I then removed them one by one and always removed and added android afterwards, and built again until the error message disappeared.

Then, I just uninstalled that plugin in my main project, added android, and installed the plugin again. The error message has since disappeared.

Maybe this is helpful for someone.

Comment: try to remove and install platform again.

Comment: @nexus, could you plz say what was the plugin caused this problem for you? You could help some people with this simple information!

Comment: I don't know... I can recommend react-native now, switched here with the project...