# Nodejs lodash issue in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, lodash

Windows 10 64bit

I am trying to play with this repo: https://github.com/mailgun/node-prelaunch

I have Mongodb up and running, along with node.js, but can't seem to get node server to run.

I've installed lodash in the main directory(C:\Users\me\Desktop\myproject\node-prelaunch) where package.js holds dependencies but am still getting thrown these errors:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\myproject\node-prelaunch>node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './lodash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename     (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load     (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require     (module.js:353:17)
    at require     (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>     (C:\Users\me\Desktop\myproject\node-    prelaunch\node_modules\express-    validator\node_modules\lodash\index.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile     (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require     (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

I've reviewed this link and tried v to follow the steps meeting:[cannot find module "lodash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431187/cannot-find-module-lodash)

In the end I guess I'm not exactly sure where the file location of lodash should be installed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're importing `lodash` from the current working directory, instead of the local package index:

```
require('./lodash')
Error: Cannot find module './lodash'
```

`./lodash` is a relative path. It means `<current directory>/lodash` Try using the name without prefix:

```
require('lodash')
```