# I get an error using NodeJs modules

Tags: node.js

I've created my first NodeJS module using `lodash`. When I install my module using `npm i mymodule --save` and run my `index.js` script using `require('lodash')` I get an error with a sub module...

Error : `Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'`

`lodash` is well installed but not in the root directory, in the modules directory...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431187/cannot-find-module-lodash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot find module "lodash"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431187/cannot-find-module-lodash)

Answer (score 0):

In the source tree of your module you need to run:

```
npm install lodash --save
```

And then publish a new version of your module to npm.

The package.json of your module needs to have `lodash` in its dependencies. If it doesn't then it will not get installed together with your module.