# ReactJs - Cannot find module 'lodash.template' - persistent error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have had problem with this module.

I tried this command:

```
npm install --save lodash
```

and apparently works fine, but I would like help figuring out why this persistent error occurs.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot find module "lodash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431187/cannot-find-module-lodash)

Comment: I think you need to install [`lodash.template`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.template) instead.