# rules_nodejs: Cannot find module 'lodash'

Tags: node.js, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to setup for the first time `bazel` with `rules_nodejs` on the dummy project.
The project structure is organised as follows:

[image]

The folder `app1` contains NODE application and the folder `app2` will be a GO based application.

The `index.js` is a very simple application:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const numbers = [1, 5, 8, 10, 1, 5, 15, 42, 5];
const uniqNumbers = _.uniq(numbers);
console.log(uniqNumbers);
```

Running the application with the command:

```
bazel run //app1
```

it shows the error message:

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'app1':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_developer/de6f8818d27e2451d76ec34773e78a6e/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 965, column 13, in _yarn_install_impl
                fail("yarn_install failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stdout, result.stderr))
Error in fail: yarn_install failed: yarn install v1.22.11
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
 (error Couldn't find any versions for "lodash" that matches "ˆ4.17.21"
)
ERROR: /Users/developer/node/bazel_play/WORKSPACE.bazel:22:13: fetching yarn_install rule //external:app1: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_developer/de6f8818d27e2451d76ec34773e78a6e/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl", line 965, column 13, in _yarn_install_impl
                fail("yarn_install failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stdout, result.stderr))
Error in fail: yarn_install failed: yarn install v1.22.11
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
 (error Couldn't find any versions for "lodash" that matches "ˆ4.17.21"
)
ERROR: /Users/developer/node/bazel_play/app1/BUILD.bazel:3:14: //app1:app1 depends on @app1//lodash:lodash in repository @app1 which failed to fetch. no such package '@app1//lodash': yarn_install failed: yarn install v1.22.11
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
 (error Couldn't find any versions for "lodash" that matches "ˆ4.17.21"
)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//app1:app1' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.591s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

I assume the problem is the `lodash` module is missing. How can I do `yarn install` with bazel command?
All source files can be found here:
https://github.com/softshipper/bazel_play

And also could anyone please explain the purpose of [yarn_install](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/Built-ins.html#yarn_install) rule?

Comment: You need to install in lodash in softshipper/bazel_play folder first. And refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431187/cannot-find-module-lodash for more. Then you can build your repo with bazel. 

$ npm install lodash --save